# How to turn a formtastic button into a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I am trying to style my formtastic submit button as a link instead of a button.

```
<%= f.actions do %>
  <%= f.action :submit, :label => "Sign in", :as => :link %>
<% end %>
```

and the above gives me a "Formtastic::UnsupportedMethodForAction" error.

I found the following sample code from [rdoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic#The_Available_Inputs](http://rdoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic#The_Available_Inputs)

```
<%= f.actions do %>
  <%= f.action :submit, :as => :button %>
  <%= f.action :cancel, :as => :link %>
<% end %>
```

and the above code will fail also if I change it to

```
<%= f.action :submit, :as => :link %>
```

is the :as => :link not supported for :submit ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will generate `<input type="button" value="Sign in">`

If you want an link that responds to an action use `link_to "Profile", :controller => "profiles", :action => "create", :id => @profile, :method => :post`

Answer (score 2):

You should rather do this using CSS. Try something like

```
#submit-button-selector {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: inline;
}
```